# HTTP Request in Node Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I know how http request works and I know how to send and receive response.
This is the sample code of http request.

```
var http = require('http');    
var options = {
host: 'www.nodejitsu.com',
path: '/',    
port: '1337',    
method: 'POST'
};

callback = function(response) {
 var str = ''
 response.on('data', function (chunk) {
 str += chunk;
});

  response.on('end', function () {
   console.log(str);
  });      

}

var req = http.request(options, callback);

req.write("hello world!");
req.end();
```

In my site everything working fine Server B send request to server A and server A response to server B. But, one time I face a problem when there is huge no of traffic on server A and it was unable to receive any request from server B which halt the whole process.

So is there is any error block in request to handle this type of errors ?
I googled alot and try this type of foolish things but it does not work for me

```
callback = function(response,error) {

 if(error){
   console.log(error)
 }else{
   var str = ''
   response.on('data', function (chunk) {
   str += chunk;
   });
   response.on('error', function (err) {
   console.log(err);
   }); 
 }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
var req = http.request(options,callback);

req.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});
```

as given here:
http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback